# Apex trigger to throw custom validation based on related list field

Tags: apex

Here is my requirement.

I have 2 objects

**Object 1.** Opportunity

**Fields:**

1.Stage

2.Primary_Purchase__c(Primary purchase record from related list)

**Object 2**. Purchase__c

**Fields:**

```
1. Count__c(Field to validate before update on opportunity)

2. Opportunity__c(lookup field to Opportunity)

3. Purchases2(Child Relationship Name)

4. Primary__c(Checkbox)
```

From Purchase__c have a Lookup to Opportunity and on Opportunity there is a field Primary_Purchase__c which is nothing but the Primary among all related purchases for that Opportunity.

Now when I try to update "Stage" on Opportunity to "Closed-Won" need to validate a field on Count__c on primary Purchase__c record from related list and if count=0 should throw my custom validation.

Apex Trigger(Not working for my functionality/requirement):

```
trigger countvalidateOnOpp on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
    Set<Id> oppsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();

    for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity old = Trigger.oldMap.get(newOpp.Id);

        if (newOpp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            oppsToUpdate.add(newOpp.Id);
        }
    }

    List<Purchase__c> purchases = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Primary__c ,Count__c
                                   FROM Purchase__c
                                   WHERE Opportunity__c in :oppsToUpdate
                                   AND Primary__c = TRUE];

    try
    {
        for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){

        if(purchases != null && purchases.size() > 0)
        {
            for (Purchase__c pur : purchases) {
                if(pur.Primary__c = true && pur.Count__c>0) { 
                  opp.addError('Cannot Update Opp');  
                }

            }

        }
    }
  }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Trigger.new[0].addError(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Note you will never throw this validation `before insert` since the record cannot yet have children. Don'y you just need to change `pur.Count__c>0` to `pur.Count__c==0`?

Comment: what if you don't get any record with this condition. Also I don't think you need nested loop here.

Comment: @Andrian: I did try that ==0 but still my trigger not throwing the validation message

Comment: Is Purchase__c master-detail to Opportunity, or just a lookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this should get you close. Basically, we use AggregateResult to quickly find the values we're interested in. We use a little trick to populate the map with an aliased field to save the extra loops. This code also fixes a number of probable logic errors in your code. This code assumes that a closed won opportunity must have a primary purchase, and that purchase's Count field must not be 0.

```
trigger countValidateOpp on Opportunity(before insert, before update) {
    // Empty map by default
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> ar = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>();
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        // Check for closed won opps
        Set<Id> opportunityId = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
           if(record.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
               opportunityId.add(record.Id);
           }
        }
        // If any are closed, do a query
        if(!opportunityId.isEmpty()) {
            ar = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
                [SELECT Opportunity__c Id, SUM(Count__c) sum
                 FROM Purchase__c
                 WHERE Opportunity__c = :opportunityId AND 
                       Primary__c = TRUE
                 GROUP BY Opportunity__c]
            );
        }
    }
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        // if matching condition, report error
        if(record.StageName == 'Closed Won' && 
             (ar.get(record.Id) == null || ((Decimal)ar.get(record.Id).get('sum')) == 0) {
            record.addError('No primary purchase with count more than 0.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly I need to throw the validation if there is NULL on this count field how to make this filter.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner Perhaps just add "AND Count__c <> null" in the query?

Answer (score 1):

If Purchase has a master-lookup field to opportunity, just create a new Rollup Summary field, using the Sum operator on Purchase records where Primary is true. You can then reduce this to just a validation rule:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Closed Won"), Primary_Purchase_Sum__c=0)
```

Comment: Nope, its a Lookup so need to go with your trigger.